# Hardcoded string "blablabla", should use @string resource

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, warnings, visual-studio-2019

So I'm developing a quiz app for a school project and suddenly have those annoying warning. 
I tried to fix this by a solution I saw here but it didn't help and it's still showing those warning.
P.S i know I should do that with colors too

[image: activity_main.xml]

[image: string.xml]

Comment: It looks like your strings.xml is not saved, save it and rebuild your project, it should not show the warnings anymore.

Comment: File->invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0):

Please Click On `Sync Now` then `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project`